# Android Deep Link Web Fallback

Tags: android, deep-linking

I've enabled Deep Linking and also created the `association.json` in the `.well-known` Folder.

When clicking on a URL the App opens the related content.

I've a button in my App to open the Content in a Web Browser. But opening the link again with a VIEW intent it opens again the App.

I saw that I could try to set the `com.android.chrome` Package in the Intent, but this is not a clean solutions because some Android users may use an alternative Browser.

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: I think you can create an intent choose and remove (blacklist) your own package by filtering the results.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it works fine for you with other browsers.
Google has modified the way chrome browser handles intent, in Android 25 or later. It is no longer possible to launch an Android app by setting an iframe's src attribute.
Checkout following link:
https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents